# Is there a way to right-justify names of speakers in a script?

Tags: tables, packages

I'm working on typesetting an edition of Renaissance colloquia (scripted conversations) and looking through the various packages I've found for doing this sort of thing I both am overwhelmed and haven't yet found what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to achieve the right justification of the (abbreviated) names of the speakers and the full justification of the things they're saying?

For what it's worth, I'm working in pdfLaTeX.

[image]

Comment: You could use a longtable `{rp{0.8\textwidth}}`.  With the array package you could automatically switch to bold in the left column.

Comment: I would use a description list with the `\item[Mi.]` with the item lable set flush right to some specified width and in bold (you could define that directly or using enumitem package